# Limiting processes by memory under Linux

Tags: linux, memory, process

We must launch several hungry processes on a Linux system. These processes often need several Go (~5Go) of memory to run (total memory: 16Go RAM + 2Go swap).

- At first, when the system was running out of memory, the OOM-killer killed processes, we had to reboot the system each time it happened.
- Then, we have tried to use the overcommit_memory (= 2) + overcommit_ratio (= 75) parameters, so processes are not launched when the situation is getting critical. So, no need to reboot the server anymore. But our launching script now report dozens of errors when the limit is reached : the new processes are immediately in error, the processes are never launched.
- So now we are looking for a solution to launch "as many" processes as we want, and then they would be delayed/paused or anything, waiting for their brothers to stop... Does it exist?

Comment: this should go here http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this little tool to allow any number of jobs to be run in parallel, or alternatively limit the degree of parallelism. Just read the comments in the header to see how to use it - you could limit the number of jobs to 2 at a time or 3 or something like that, but submit them all in one go. It uses REDIS underneath, which is free and really easy to install.

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# File: core
# Author: Mark Setchell
# 
# Primitive, but effective tool for managing parallel execution of jobs in the
# shell. Based on, and requiring REDIS.
#
# Usage:
#
# core -i 8 # Initialise to 8 cores, or specify 0 to use all available cores
# for i in {0..63}
# do
#   # Wait for a core, do a process, release core
#   (core -p; process; core -v)&
# done
# wait
################################################################################
function usage {
    echo "Usage: core -i ncores # Initialise with ncores. Use 0 for all cores."
    echo "       core -p        # Wait (forever) for free core."
    echo "       core -v        # Release core."
    exit 1
}

function init {
    # Delete list of cores in REDIS
    echo DEL cores | redis-cli > /dev/null 2>&1
    for i in `seq 1 $NCORES`
    do
       # Add another core to list of cores in REDIS
       echo LPUSH cores 1 | redis-cli > /dev/null 2>&1
    done
    exit 0
}

function WaitForCore {
    # Wait forever for a core to be available
    echo BLPOP cores 0 | redis-cli > /dev/null 2>&1
    exit 0
}

function ReleaseCore {
    # Release or give back a core
    echo LPUSH cores 1 | redis-cli > /dev/null 2>&1
    exit 0
}

################################################################################
# Main
################################################################################
while getopts "i:pv" optname
  do
    case "$optname" in
      "i")
        if [ $OPTARG -lt 1 ]; then
           NCORES=`sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu`;    # May differ if not on OSX
        else
           NCORES=$OPTARG
        fi
    init $NCORES
        ;;
      "p")
    WaitForCore
        ;;
      "v")
    ReleaseCore
        ;;
      "?")
        echo "Unknown option $OPTARG"
        ;;
    esac
done
usage
```